# loggedIn state reverts back to false after Logging in and doesn't allow me to guard route

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I'm trying to guard my routes with `state: { loggedIn: false },` when I login from my Login.vue component the goal is to trigger an action `this.$store.dispatch('setLogin')` that mutates the state of  `loggedIn` to true. There is then navigation guard that is suppose to prevent me form seeing my Login.vue and Regester.vue components. The problem is that it seems like the state changes to true, but not the base state: allowing me to keep hitting the `/auth/login` and `/auth/register` routes.

**Routes**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'auth',
    component: Auth,
    children: [
      { name: 'login', path: 'login', component: Login },
      { name: 'register', path: 'register', component: Register },
    ],
    meta: {
      requiresVisitor: true,
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/logout',
    name: 'logout',
    component: Logout
  }
]
```

**Login Component**

```
login() {
    this.$http.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
        this.$http.post('/login', {
            email: this.username,
            password: this.password,
        }).then(response2 => {
            this.$store.dispatch('setLogin')
            this.$store.dispatch('getUser')
            alert(this.$store.state.loggedIn)
            this.$router.push({ name: 'Home' })
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
            const key = Object.keys(error.response.data.errors)[0]
            this.errorMessage = error.response.data.errors[key][0]
        })
    });
}
```

**Vuex**

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedIn: false,
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) || null,
  },
  mutations: {
    setLogin: (state) => {
      state.loggedIn = true
    },
    SET_USER_DATA (state, userData) {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userData))
      state.user = userData;
    },
    removeUser(state) {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      state.user = null;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    getUser(context) {
      if (context.state.loggedIn) {
        alert('hit');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          axios.get('api/user')
            .then(response => {
              context.commit('SET_USER_DATA', response.data.data)
              resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
              reject(error)
            })
        })
      }
    },
    setLogin(context){
      context.commit('setLogin')
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

It's strange because `alert(this.$store.state.loggedIn)` renders true, but when I go back the auth link there's a mounted state alert that comes back false.

Here's my navigation guards as well:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      if (!store.state.loggedIn) {
        next({
            name: 'login',
        })
      } else {
      next()
      }
  } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresVisitor)) {
      if (store.state.loggedIn) {
      next({
          name: 'Home',
      })
      return
      } else {
      next()
      }
  } else {
      next()
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the loggedIn user in local storage:

```
setLogin: (state) => {
 state.loggedIn = localStorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'true')
 state.loggedIn = true
},
```

Then your state should look like:

```
state: {
    loggedIn: localStorage.getItem('loggedIn') || null,
},
```